# accessing the properties of object using $ in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have created an object and I want to use $ to access them and print them in the console but I don't get the desired result.

```
const person ={
 name:'tom',
 age:28,
 location:{

    city:'tokyo',
    temp:92 
 }
};
const name=person.name;
const age=person.age;
console.log('${name} is ${age}' );
```

I am getting ${name} is ${age} in console which instead should be tom is 28.

Comment: Wrong quotes ``?

Comment: Aluan is correct-- to do string interpolation in JavaScript you need to use tickmarks (``) to wrap your string.  Please note this may not have full browser capability.

Comment: It's called [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). You need to use backtick `\``.

Comment: can u write the correct version instead of downvoting it ?

Comment: @satyajeetjha because it seems you did not look at an example or could not be bothered to copy and paste. Why didn't you ask Google?

Comment: Probably I did the wrong googling which landed me to some useless place and so I asked my question here.

Answer (score 4):

As [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) only recognise ``.

> Template literals are enclosed by the back-tick (``)  (grave accent) character instead of double or single quotes.

Accordingly change your line to

```js
const person ={
 name:'tom',
 age:28,
 location:{

    city:'tokyo',
    temp:92 
 }
};
const name=person.name;
const age=person.age;
console.log(`${name} is ${age}` );
```

Answer (score 0):

> Template literals are enclosed by the back-tick (``) (grave accent)
>   character instead of double or single quotes.

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azmvxfsd/)

```
const persond ={
 name:'tom',
 age:28,
 location:{

    city:'tokyo',
    temp:92 
 }
};
```

Try function like this,

```
function people(arr, n, a) {
  console.log(arr[0] + n + arr[1] + a + arr[2]);
}
```

Call it like

```
people `Woah, ${persond.name} is ${persond.age}?`;
```

It should works

> Woah, tom is 28?